# tkinter.mainloop does not work

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I am trying to create a basic Tkinter window.
According to on-line tutorials, to create a window one must use the following:

```
import Tkinter
window=Tkinter.Tk()
window.mainloop()
```

But when I try the same code python directly displays the window in `window=Tkinter.Tk()` and `window.mainloop()` has no effect.
Can anyone explain why ?

EDIT: The code works perfectly when I put it in a file and run it. It just doesn't work from interactive prompt.

Comment: Are you doing this via the interactive prompt?

Comment: What do you mean by "directly" and "has no effect"? When I put your code in a file and do "python the_file.py", it works as expected.

Comment: @dano yes, via the prompt.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What magic prevents Tkinter programs from blocking in interactive shell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20891710/what-magic-prevents-tkinter-programs-from-blocking-in-interactive-shell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `mainloop` is there so that you can interact with the Window once it's created. If you had a Python script that only did this:

```
import Tkinter
window = Tkinter.Tk()
```

The script would exit immediately after `window` was created, so you'd be luckily to even see it get drawn before it disappeared as the script exited. (That is if `window` was even drawn at all; in my tests on both Linux and Windows, `window` was never drawn unless `mainloop` was called; even if I put a call to `time.sleep` after the `Tkinter.Tk()` call, `window` would only be drawn without a `mainloop` call in the interactive prompt).

The `mainloop()` also (and most importantly) allows `Tkinter` to listen for events to occur on the `Tk` object, such as pressing buttons, radios, etc. that might be embedded in it, and dispatch those events to methods you have bound to the event being triggered. Without that functionality you'd just have a window that you can look at and not much else.

Comment: But I actually have a window open at `window=Tkinter.Tk()` . I would have posted an image but I don't have  enough reputation.

Comment: @AadityaMNair Yeah, it will show up in the interactive prompt for me, too. It won't show up if I put it in a Python script and run it, which is how you normally use GUI applications.