# How `input` can substitute tkinter mainloop?

Tags: python, tkinter, gnome-terminal

From this question: [What magic prevents Tkinter programs from blocking in interactive shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20891710/what-magic-prevents-tkinter-programs-from-blocking-in-interactive-shell) which is answered by @abarnert:

> *If stdin is a TTY, then, each time it tries to fetch a line with `input()`, various bits of the `code` module, the built-in REPL, etc., Python calls any installed `PyOS_InputHook` instead of just reading from stdin.*
>
> *What `Tkinter` does is similar. It's more complicated because it has to deal with Windows, but on *nix it's doing something pretty similar to `readline`. Except that it's calling `Tcl_DoOneEvent` each time through the loop.*

I got riddled by this behavior. `input` isn't exactly the same as `mainloop` of tkinter, therefore, `Tcl_DoOneEvent` won't be called by `input`. It's understandable that `input` and `mainloop` behave similarly, but `input` calls `PyOS_InputHook` instead of `Tcl_DoOneEvent`.

At the interactive shell when running Python interactively, I use `gnome-terminal`, running this script:

```
#main.py
from tkinter import *
win = Tk()
Button(win, command=(lambda:print('pressed'))).pack(side=TOP)
```

executing the file:

```
$python3 -i main.py
>>> print("something")       # I didn't press enter here
```

I get the window on screen and pressing the button 2 times this is what I get in the terminal:

```
>>> print("something")pressed
pressed
```

after pressing enter the window responded to events, in terminal again:

```
>>> print("something")pressed
pressed

something
>>> pressed
```

Of course, there's no `input` in `main.py`, but running Python interpreter  interactively does demonstrate the point. Generally, how `input` and the interactive interpreter obviate the need to call `Tk.mainloop()`?

*Edit:* 
It would be easier to grasp if someone could possibly show us the inner working of `input` and the interactive interpreter *with pseudo-code or Python code.*

This might seem to be a duplicate, I hope this question will complement the previous one and add more clarification to it.

Comment: I can't see anything about this question that is different from the other one.

Comment: @BryanOakley I forgot to include one thing in my question so I edited the question: *Edit: It would be easier to grasp if someone could possibly show us the inner working of `input` and the interactive interpreter with pseudo-code or Python code.* Also in my first paragraph: *I got riddled by this behavior. `input` isn't exactly the same as `mainloop`...* I stated my confusion.

Comment: As it turned out, behind the scenes, `_tkinter.c` overrides `PyOS_InputHook` to integrate the interpreter's prompt with its event loop: [*"Overriding this hook can be used to integrate the interpreter's prompt with other event loops, as done in the :file:Modules/_tkinter.c in the Python source code."*](https://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/672614d809a1)