# Tkinter understanding mainloop

Tags: python, tkinter

Till now, I used to end my Tkinter programs with: `tk.mainloop()`, or nothing would show up! See example:

```
from Tkinter import *
import random
import time

tk = Tk()
tk.title = "Game"
tk.resizable(0,0)
tk.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)

canvas = Canvas(tk, width=500, height=400, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack()

class Ball:
    def __init__(self, canvas, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.id = canvas.create_oval(10, 10, 25, 25, fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 245, 100)
    def draw(self):
        pass

ball = Ball(canvas, "red")

tk.mainloop()
```

However, when tried the next step in this program (making the ball move by time), the book am reading from, says to do the following. So I changed the draw function to:

```
def draw(self):
    self.canvas.move(self.id, 0, -1)
```

and add the following code to my program:

```
while 1:
    ball.draw()
    tk.update_idletasks()
    tk.update()
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

But I noticed that adding this block of code, made the use of `tk.mainloop()` useless, since everything would show up even without it!!!

*At this moment I should mention that my book never talks about `tk.mainloop()` (maybe because it uses Python 3) but I learned about it searching the web since my programs didn't work by copying book's code!*

So I tried doing the following that would not work!!!

```
while 1:
    ball.draw()
    tk.mainloop()
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

What's going on? What does `tk.mainloop()`? What does `tk.update_idletasks()` and `tk.update()` do and how that differs from `tk.mainloop()`? Should I use the above loop?`tk.mainloop()`? or both in my programs?

Comment: About mainloop: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683217/tkinter-when-do-i-need-to-call-mainloop

Comment: these question are connected somehow... i don't think it would be nice making 3 questions in 3 topics that talk almost about the same thing... :|

Comment: I suggest getting a different book...

Comment: *Working links:* [Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112021403id_/https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.update-method) you have something about the `update` function. [Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112021403id_/https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.update_idletasks-method) about `update_idletasks`..

Answer (score 143, accepted):

`tk.mainloop()` *blocks*.  It means that execution of your Python commands halts there.  You can see that by writing:

```
while 1:
    ball.draw()
    tk.mainloop()
    print("hello")   #NEW CODE
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

You will never see the output from the print statement. Because there is no loop, the ball doesn't move.

On the other hand, the methods `update_idletasks()` and `update()` here:

```
while True:
    ball.draw()
    tk.update_idletasks()
    tk.update()
```

...do not block; after those methods finish, execution will continue, so the `while` loop will execute over and over, which makes the ball move.

An infinite loop containing the method calls `update_idletasks()` and `update()` can act as a substitute for calling `tk.mainloop()`.  Note that the whole while loop can be said to *block* just like `tk.mainloop()` because nothing after the while loop will execute.

However, `tk.mainloop()` is not a substitute for just the lines:

```
tk.update_idletasks()
tk.update()
```

Rather, `tk.mainloop()` is a substitute for the whole while loop:

```
while True:
    tk.update_idletasks()
    tk.update()
```

**Response to comment:**

Here is what the [tcl docs](http://wiki.tcl.tk/13859) say:

> Update idletasks
>
> This subcommand of update flushes all currently-scheduled idle events
> from Tcl's event queue. Idle events are used to postpone processing
> until “there is nothing else to do”, with the typical use case for
> them being Tk's redrawing and geometry recalculations. By postponing
> these until Tk is idle, expensive redraw operations are not done until
> everything from a cluster of events (e.g., button release, change of
> current window, etc.) are processed at the script level. This makes Tk
> seem much faster, but if you're in the middle of doing some long
> running processing, it can also mean that no idle events are processed
> for a long time. By calling update idletasks, redraws due to internal
> changes of state are processed immediately. (Redraws due to system
> events, e.g., being deiconified by the user, need a full update to be
> processed.)
>
> APN As described in Update considered harmful, use of update to handle
> redraws not handled by update idletasks has many issues. Joe English
> in a comp.lang.tcl posting describes an alternative:

So `update_idletasks()` causes some subset of events to be processed that `update()` causes to be processed.

From the [update docs](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1252):

> update ?idletasks?
>
> The update command is used to bring the application “up to date” by
> entering the Tcl event loop repeatedly until all pending events
> (including idle callbacks) have been processed.
>
> If the idletasks keyword is specified as an argument to the command,
> then no new events or errors are processed; only idle callbacks are
> invoked. This causes operations that are normally deferred, such as
> display updates and window layout calculations, to be performed
> immediately.
>
> KBK (12 February 2000) -- My personal opinion is that the [update]
> command is not one of the best practices, and a programmer is well
> advised to avoid it. I have seldom if ever seen a use of [update] that
> could not be more effectively programmed by another means, generally
> appropriate use of event callbacks. By the way, this caution applies
> to all the Tcl commands (vwait and tkwait are the other common
> culprits) that enter the event loop recursively, with the exception of
> using a single [vwait] at global level to launch the event loop inside
> a shell that doesn't launch it automatically.
>
> The commonest purposes for which I've seen [update] recommended are:
>
> 1. Keeping the GUI alive while some long-running calculation is
>    executing. See Countdown program for an alternative. 2) Waiting for a window to be configured before doing things like
>    geometry management on it. The alternative is to bind on events such
>    as  that notify the process of a window's geometry. See
>    Centering a window for an alternative.
>
> What's wrong with update? There are several answers. First, it tends
> to complicate the code of the surrounding GUI. If you work the
> exercises in the Countdown program, you'll get a feel for how much
> easier it can be when each event is processed on its own callback.
> Second, it's a source of insidious bugs. The general problem is that
> executing [update] has nearly unconstrained side effects; on return
> from [update], a script can easily discover that the rug has been
> pulled out from under it. There's further discussion of this
> phenomenon over at Update considered harmful.

.....

> Is there any chance I can make my program work without the while loop?

Yes, but things get a little tricky.  You might think something like the following would work:

```
class Ball:
    def __init__(self, canvas, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.id = canvas.create_oval(10, 10, 25, 25, fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 245, 100)

    def draw(self):
        while True:
           self.canvas.move(self.id, 0, -1)

ball = Ball(canvas, "red")
ball.draw()
tk.mainloop()
```

The problem is that ball.draw() will cause execution to enter an infinite loop in the draw() method, so tk.mainloop() will never execute, and your widgets will never display.   In gui programming, infinite loops have to be avoided at all costs in order to keep the widgets responsive to user input, e.g. mouse clicks.

So, the question is: how do you execute something over and over again without actually creating an infinite loop?  Tkinter has an answer for that problem: a widget's `after()` method:

```
from Tkinter import *
import random
import time

tk = Tk()
tk.title = "Game"
tk.resizable(0,0)
tk.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)

canvas = Canvas(tk, width=500, height=400, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack()

class Ball:
    def __init__(self, canvas, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.id = canvas.create_oval(10, 10, 25, 25, fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 245, 100)

    def draw(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 0, -1)
        self.canvas.after(1, self.draw)  #(time_delay, method_to_execute)


       

ball = Ball(canvas, "red")
ball.draw()  #Changed per Bryan Oakley's comment
tk.mainloop()
```

The after() method doesn't *block* (it actually creates another thread of execution), so execution continues on in your python program after after() is called, which means tk.mainloop() executes next, so your widgets get configured and displayed.  The after() method also allows your widgets to remain responsive to other user input.  Try running the following program, and then click your mouse on different spots on the canvas:

```
from Tkinter import *
import random
import time

root = Tk()
root.title = "Game"
root.resizable(0,0)
root.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)

canvas = Canvas(root, width=500, height=400, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack()

class Ball:
    def __init__(self, canvas, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.id = canvas.create_oval(10, 10, 25, 25, fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 245, 100)

        self.canvas.bind("<Button-1>", self.canvas_onclick)
        self.text_id = self.canvas.create_text(300, 200, anchor='se')
        self.canvas.itemconfig(self.text_id, text='hello')

    def canvas_onclick(self, event):
        self.canvas.itemconfig(
            self.text_id, 
            text="You clicked at ({}, {})".format(event.x, event.y)
        )

    def draw(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 0, -1)
        self.canvas.after(50, self.draw)


       

ball = Ball(canvas, "red")
ball.draw()  #Changed per Bryan Oakley's comment.
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Regarding also another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29158811/whats-the-difference-between-update-and-update-idletasks) that I have just posted, why should you use `update_idletasks` before `update`, since the latter does everything the former does?

Comment: There is never a reason to call both `update_idletasks` and `update` at the same time. `update` does everything `update_idletasks` does, and more.

Comment: At the very end of your program you start the animation with `canvas.after(0, ball.draw)`. You don't need to use `after` here -- you can directly call `ball.draw` to kick things off.

Comment: This statement is incorrect: _"The after() method doesn't block (it actually creates another thread of execution)"_ - `after` does _not_ create another thread of execution. Tkinter is single-threaded. `after` merely adds a function to a queue.

Answer (score 31):

```
while 1:
    root.update()
```

... is (very!) *roughly* similar to:

```
root.mainloop()
```

The difference is, `mainloop` is the correct way to code and the infinite loop is subtly incorrect. I suspect, though, that the vast majority of the time, either will work. It's just that `mainloop` is a much cleaner solution. After all, calling `mainloop` is essentially this under the covers:

```
while the_window_has_not_been_destroyed():
    wait_until_the_event_queue_is_not_empty()
    event = event_queue.pop()
    event.handle()
```

... which, as you can see, isn't much different than your own while loop. So, why create your own infinite loop when tkinter already has one you can use?

Put in the simplest terms possible: **always call `mainloop` as the last logical line of code in your program**. That's how Tkinter was designed to be used.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using an MVC / MVA design pattern, with multiple types of "views".  One type is a "GuiView", which is a Tk window.  I pass a view reference to my window object which does things like link buttons back to view functions (which the adapter / controller class also calls).

In order to do that, the view object constructor needed to be completed prior to creating the window object.  After creating and displaying the window, I wanted to do some initial tasks with the view automatically.  At first I tried doing them post mainloop(), but that didn't work because mainloop() blocked!

As such, I created the window object and used tk.update() to draw it.  Then, I kicked off my initial tasks, and finally started the mainloop.

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Window(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, view=None ):
        tk.Frame.__init__( self, master )
        self.view_ = view       
        """ Setup window linking it to the view... """

class GuiView( MyViewSuperClass ):

    def open( self ):
        self.tkRoot_ = tk.Tk()
        self.window_ = Window( master=None, view=self )
        self.window_.pack()
        self.refresh()
        self.onOpen()
        self.tkRoot_.mainloop()         

    def onOpen( self ):        
        """ Do some initial tasks... """

    def refresh( self ):        
        self.tkRoot_.update()
```