# How do I get an entry widget to save what I input? Python Tkinter

Tags: python, button, tkinter, widget, tkinter-entry

I want to make an entry widget that inputs personal details, however I want to save those details as variables, so I can write them in a txt file.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
Label(root, text = "Childs First name").grid(row = 0, sticky = W)
Label(root, text = "Childs Surname").grid(row = 1, sticky = W)
Label(root, text = "Childs Year of Birth").grid(row = 2, sticky = W)
Label(root, text = "Childs Month of Birth").grid(row = 3, sticky = W)
Label(root, text = "Childs Day of Birth").grid(row = 4, sticky = W)

Fname = Entry(root)
Sname = Entry(root)
x = Entry(root)
y = Entry(root)
z = Entry(root)


Fname.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
Sname.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
x.grid(row = 3, column = 1)
y.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
z.grid(row = 4, column = 1)

Fname = Fname.get
Sname = Sname.get
x = x.get
y = y.get
z = z.get
mainloop()
```

My code works absolutely fine, however it doesn't save what I inputted, let alone save it within a variable. I'm obviously missing chunks of code, but I don't know what code.

P.S: Also, if it's not too much, how would I make a button to continue on to the next lines of code?

Answer (score 2):

This has not been answered yet so here's a complete chunk of code that does what you are requesting.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
Label(root, text = "Childs First name").grid(row = 0, sticky = W)
Label(root, text = "Childs Surname").grid(row = 1, sticky = W)
Label(root, text = "Childs Year of Birth").grid(row = 2, sticky = W)
Label(root, text = "Childs Month of Birth").grid(row = 3, sticky = W)
Label(root, text = "Childs Day of Birth").grid(row = 4, sticky = W)

Fname = Entry(root)
Sname = Entry(root)
x = Entry(root)
y = Entry(root)
z = Entry(root)


Fname.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
Sname.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
x.grid(row = 3, column = 1)
y.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
z.grid(row = 4, column = 1)

def getInput():

    a = Fname.get()
    b = Sname.get()
    c = x.get()
    d = y.get()
    e = z.get()
    root.destroy()

    global params
    params = [a,b,c,d,e]


Button(root, text = "submit",
           command = getInput).grid(row = 5, sticky = W)
mainloop()
```

It is not very elegant but it does exactly what you are asking with the minimum amount of changes to your version.

If you run it, and input `1`,`2`,`3`,`4`, and `5` to your entry fields, then click on the `submit` button I added, and print the `params` `list`, you get:

```
>>> params
['1', '2', '4', '3', '5']
```

If for some reason you don't want the window to close after submission, omit `root.destroy()` and take it from there.

Notice that `getInput` as a `Button` parameter does not have parentheses so that it is only called when the button is clicked, not when this line is executed.

Finally, I am not sure what you mean by your last question, 'how would I make a button to continue on to the next lines of code'. The `mainloop()` thingy you have added in the end makes sure (among other things) that the rest of your code is not executed until the box is closed (it also starts a loop collecting events and making sure the events get processed). So once you click `submit` and the window closes, the rest of the code gets executed. You will further understand this if you add a `print('hi')` statement before or after the `mainloop()` line. If you add it before, the string will be printed 'simultaneously' with the opening of the window; if you put it after, it will be printed once the window is closed. (for additional information on `mainloop()`, have a look at extensive discussions in stack [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683217/when-do-i-need-to-call-mainloop-in-a-tkinter-application) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29158220/tkinter-understanding-mainloop))

Answer (score 1):

For accepting an input from user in tkinter, I always use the following code, with foolproof results -

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
Label(root,text='Your input prompt').pack()
t1=Text(root, height=2, width=8)
t1.pack()
```

Now here's the main part:

```
def value(t):
    x=t.get('1.0','end-1c')
    return x
```

Obviously you need to trigger this after you have entered a value in the text box, and presumably by using a button that says 'Submit' or 'confirm' or whatever.

```
def submit():
    a=value(t1)
    print(a)
Button(root, text='Submit', command=submit).pack()
```

A couple of notes:

1. Height and width in Text widget are optional.
2. Note the widget is TEXT, not ENTRY. I haven't seen the code work with entry.
3. The value inside get "end-1c" is to remove the extra newline character tkinter adds on its own.
4. You can obviously use grid instead of pack().

Hope you find this useful

Answer (score 0):

Entry widgets have a `get` method which can be used to get the values when you need them. Your "save" function simply needs to call this function before writing to a file.

For example:

```
def save():
    x_value = x.get()
    y_value = y.get()
    z_value = z.get()
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks! So if i were to type print(x), it would then print what I inputted

Comment: @user6842389: no, you would have to print `x_value`. `x` is a widget, not the value _in_ the widget.

Comment: Okay,  however how would i access the x_value since its in a function, and i want to access it outside the function

Comment: @user6842389: you're missing the point. You can get the value anytime you want, in any function you want. You get the value when you need it.

Comment: Wait i dont understand how this is meant to work, since I cant confirm that its saved, and I have to press the x button, which means nothing had been saved

Comment: @user6842389: _anywhere_ in your code where you need the current value in the entry widget `x`, use `x.get()`. I honestly don't know how to make that more clear. Don't use `x`, use `x.get()`.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I get an entry widget to save what I input? However I want to
> save those details as variables, **so I can write them in a txt file**.

The problem can be fixed.

- Add `import configparser`.
- `open("child_inform.ini", "r+")`
- Create `child_settings()` functions.
- Add Button widget and add keyword `command=child_settings`.

Snippet:

```
from tkinter import *
import configparser

parser_child_inform = configparser.ConfigParser()
parser_child_inform.read('child_inform.ini')

root = Tk()
root.title('Child information')

load_child_inform = open("child_inform.ini", "r+")
line = load_child_inform.readlines()
load_child_inform = line[1].split()[-1]
child_first_name = load_child_inform[2].split()[-1]

def child_settings():
    if not parser_child_inform.has_section("Child"):
        parser_child_inform.add_section('Child')
    parser_child_inform.set('Child', 'first_name', entry_child_first_name.get())
    parser_child_inform.set('Child', 'last_name', entry_child_last_name.get())
    parser_child_inform.set('Child', 'year', entry_child_year.get())
    parser_child_inform.set('Child', 'month', entry_child_month.get())
    parser_child_inform.set('Child', 'day', entry_child_day.get())

    with open("child_inform.ini", "w") as config:
        parser_child_inform.write(config)
        
    root.destroy()                         

if parser_child_inform.has_section("Child"):
    entry_child_first_name = Entry(root)
    entry_child_first_name.insert(0, parser_child_inform.get('Child', 'first_name'))
    entry_child_first_name.grid(row=0, column=1)

    entry_child_last_name = Entry(root)
    entry_child_last_name.insert(0, parser_child_inform.get('Child', 'last_name'))
    entry_child_last_name.grid(row=1, column=1)

    entry_child_year = Entry(root)
    entry_child_year.insert(0, parser_child_inform.get('Child', 'year'))
    entry_child_year.grid(row=2, column=1)

    entry_child_month = Entry(root)
    entry_child_month.insert(0, parser_child_inform.get('Child', 'month'))
    entry_child_month.grid(row=3, column=1)

    entry_child_day = Entry(root)
    entry_child_day.insert(0, parser_child_inform.get('Child', 'day'))
    entry_child_day.grid(row=4, column=1)


Label(root, text = "Childs First name").grid(row = 0, sticky = W)
Label(root, text = "Childs Surname").grid(row = 1, sticky = W)
Label(root, text = "Childs Year of Birth").grid(row = 2, sticky = W)
Label(root, text = "Childs Month of Birth").grid(row = 3, sticky = W)
Label(root, text = "Childs Day of Birth").grid(row = 4, sticky = W)

Button(root, text='Save', command=child_settings).grid(row = 5,column=1,  sticky = W)
 
mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Copied and Pasted in Notepad, Editor, etc:

```
[Child]
first_name = Adam
last_name = West
year = 1945
month = 8
day = 12
```