# Can't invoke "button" command: application has been destroyed

Tags: python, tkinter, invoke, destroy

with an error which is impossible to fix under my hands. I find a defined variable after it has been opened I want the page to close so not all windows are open however when I load new user screen once they have done filled in new user details, I put a button in to which it will redirect them to existingUserEntry page ,which it is saying it cannot invoke the button, any help is necessary thanks?

```
def existingUserEntry():
    intitialScreen.destroy()
    login = False
    global existingUserScreen, usernameEntry, passwordEntry  
    existingUserScreen = Tk() # Set up a screen
    existingUserScreen.title("Existing User Login Screen")# Set a caption
    existingUserScreen.config(bg = "WHITE")# Set the background colour
    existingUserScreen.geometry("350x150")# Set the size of the window
    # Code for the username entry box.    
    usernameLabel = Label(existingUserScreen, text = "User name:")# Username Text box
    usernameLabel.config(bg = "PALE GREEN", font=('Helvetica', 12))# Formatting Features
    usernameLabel.pack()
    usernameEntry = ttk.Entry(existingUserScreen, font = "bold", width = 30)
    usernameEntry.pack()
    # Code for the password entry box.
    passwordLabel = Label(existingUserScreen, text = "Password:")# Password Text box
    passwordLabel.config(bg = "PALE GREEN", font=('Helvetica', 12))# Formatting Features
    passwordLabel.pack()
    passwordEntry = ttk.Entry(existingUserScreen, font = "bold", width = 30, show="*")
    passwordEntry.pack() 
    # Code for the sign in button.
    signInButton = Button(existingUserScreen, text="Sign in", width=10, command=verifyLoginDetails)
    signInButton.pack(expand = 1)# Placement of the Sign In button
    existingUserScreen.mainloop()

#Code for a button to allow new users to login to profile after creating one
    newUserSignInButton = Button(newUserScreen, text=" Back to Login Screen", width=15, command=backToLoginScreen)
    newUserSignInButton.config(height= 1, width= 40)
    newUserSignInButton.pack(expand= 4)
    newUserScreen.mainloop()
    newUserScreen = Button(intitialScreen, text="Existing User Sign In", width=25, command=existingUserEntry)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def existingUserEntry():
    intitialScreen.destroy()
    ....
    newUserScreen = Button(intitialScreen,...)
```

You are destroying your `intitialScreen` at the beginning of your method then trying to add a button to that container at the end which causes the error. You need to choose existing one for your widgets.

Also, please note that,

- Don't create multiple `Tk()` instances. If you want another window (e.g. pop-up) use `Toplevel()` instead of `Tk()`. (There is only one `Tk()` in this code but it feels like you have more in your actual code)
- If you don't know what you are exactly doing, you most likely don't want to use [`mainloop()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683217/when-do-i-need-to-call-mainloop-in-a-tkinter-application) anywhere but at the end of your program.