# Tkinter not creating a window?

Tags: python, tkinter, window

I am trying to create a window with Tkinter but no window is being created and I am not receiving any error codes?

```
from tkinter import *
def login_window():
 window=Tk()
 window.title("Login")
 info_lbl = Label(window)
 info_lbl.grid(row=0, column=1)
 username_lbl = Label(window, text='Username')
 username_lbl.grid(row=1, column=1)
 username_entry = Entry(window, width=10)
 username_entry.grid(row=1, column=2)
 password_lbl = Label(window, text='Password')
 password_lbl.grid(row=2, column=1)
 password_entry = Entry(window, width=10, )
 password_entry.grid(row=2, column=2)
 ok_button = Button(window, text='Login', command = menu_window)
 ok_button.grid(row=3,column = 2,sticky =W)
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I think u should add mainloop() inside your function as well as call your login_window something like this-

```
from Tkinter import *
def login_window():
     window=Tk()
     window.title("Login")
     mainloop()
login_window()
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you never entered the main Tkinter loop. To display that window, you could add this to the bottom of the function:

```
window.mainloop()
```

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683217/when-do-i-need-to-call-mainloop-in-a-tkinter-application) and the accepted answer for a bit more information on the Tkinter main loop.