# Error when creating file opening window by using tkinter library

Tags: python, tkinter

I am referring to this post: [Tkinter not creating a window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42460883/tkinter-not-creating-a-window). And the code published there as answer returns me the same error on my code: `TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable`
This is my code:

```
import tkinter
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title = ('Project planner')
open_button = tkinter.Button(root, text='Open project...', command=open_project)
open_button.pack(side='top')
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(root, width=800, height=400, bg='white')
canvas.pack(side='bottom')
tkinter.mainloop()
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Are you running that on a server??

Comment: On Jupyther Notebook now here: [link](https://jupyter.org/try)
I can try to run it and test it on Anaconda Spyder (this evening..)
I believe this is the issue..

Comment: Are you running this notebook on your local machine or on a server?

Comment: I believe it is on server. Well I am running it on local machine, but Jupyther Notebook is located on server.

Comment: No, this code works if you host the notebook on your machine.

Comment: Ok, thank you! I will test it this evening..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should be running my code locally, then it works, it does not work on server.