# Why the tkinter window does not open when using the method "grid()"?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

# ==================================================Settings=======================================================
root = Tk()
root.title("Video Youtube Downloader") # set up the title and size.
root.configure(background='black') # set up background.
root.minsize(800, 500)
root.maxsize(800, 500)
# ==================================================Frames=======================================================
top = Frame(root, width=800, height=50,  bg='yellow').pack(side=TOP)
bottom = Frame(root, width=800, height=50,  bg='red').pack(side=BOTTOM)
left = Frame(root,  width=550, height=450, bg='black').pack(side=LEFT)
right = Frame(root, width=250, height=450, bg='blue').pack(side=RIGHT)



# ==================================================Buttons=======================================================
btn_clear_url = Button(right, text="Clear Url", font=('arial', 10, 'bold')).grid(row=1, columns=1)
```

I am trying to add buttons to the right Frame, but for some reason when I run the program the IDE shows that it is running but there is
no window. When I delete `.grid(row=1, columns=1)` the window appears.
How can I fix this bug, and add `btn_clear_url` button to the right Frame?

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. There is nothing more n the code you posted that would cause the behaviou you describe.

Comment: I think the bug as @mentalita pointed out is that I am using ".pack(side=TOP)" in the same line. Thus, when adding ".grid(row=1, columns=1)" at the same time the window is not loading.

Answer (score 2):

- First of all, you need to invoke `Tk`'s `mainloop` at the end of your code (you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683217/when-do-i-need-to-call-mainloop-in-a-tkinter-application) why).
- Another problem is chaining method calls like that. You're actually assigning return value of the last call to the variable, which is `None` in case of `grid()` and `pack()` - therefore, all your variables end up having `None` as the value. You need to separate widget instantiating call and `grid` or `pack` call and put each on its own line.
- Other than that, you're setting both `minsize` and `maxsize` to the very same size - if you're really just trying to make your window not resizable, set the size with:

  ```
  root.geometry('800x500') # for instance
  ```

  ...and after that configure `resizable` attribute:

  ```
  root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
  ```
- Also, I suggest you get rid of `from tkinter import *`, since you don't know what names that imports. It can replace names you imported earlier, and it makes it very difficult to tell where names in your program are supposed to come from. Use `import tkinter as tk` instead.

Answer (score 0):

When you place widget in a tk window you cannot use grid and pack at the same time in the same window, so you use should use pack () instead of grid()

Answer (score 0):

The problem starts with this line of code:

```
right = Frame(root, width=250, height=450, bg='blue').pack(side=RIGHT)
```

With that, `right` is set to `None` because `.pack(side=RIGHT)` returns `None`.

Next, you do this:

```
btn_clear_url = Button(right, ...)).grid(row=1, columns=1)
```

Because `right` is `None`, it's the same as `Button(root, ...)`. Since you are already using `pack` for a widget in `root`, you can't also use `grid`.

The solution -- and best practice -- is to separate widget creation from widget layout:

```
top = Frame(root, width=800, height=50,  bg='yellow')
bottom = Frame(root, width=800, height=50,  bg='red')
left = Frame(root,  width=550, height=450, bg='black')
right = Frame(root, width=250, height=450, bg='blue')

top.pack(side=TOP)
bottom.pack(side=BOTTOM)
left.pack(side=LEFT)
right.pack(side=RIGHT)
```

With the above, `right` will be properly set to the frame instance, and adding a widget to `right` and using `grid` will no longer fail.