# How can I change a label text after a specific time without after() function in tkinter python?

Tags: python, tkinter, animation

The code i tried to accomplish my result:

> ```
> from tkinter import*
> import time
> root=Tk()
> lyrics=StringVar()
> lyrics.set("unleash")
> l=Label(root,textvariable=lyrics)
> l.pack()
> def change_text():
>     lyrics.set("you!!")
>     print('ses')
>
>
> time.sleep(6.9)
> change_text()
> mainloop()
> ```

The problems in this are like the window is displayed after 10 sec. If I shift the `mainloop()` before the `time.sleep()` function the `time.sleep()` executes after the app is closed. The reason is simple that I didn't use after() function because the `after()` function doesn't accepts the sec value in decimal.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: `after` takes an argument in milliseconds, when can easily give you fractional seconds. 6.9 seconds is 6900 milliseconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `after()` function takes the delay argument in milliseconds, where you would pass `6900` instead of `6.9`. See: https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/after.html

The problem is that `mainloop()` blocks further execution. You can always use a background thread:

```
def bg_thread():
    time.sleep(6.9)
    change_text()

thread = threading.Thread(target=bg_thread)
thread.start()

mainloop()
```

Threading, of course, brings with it a whole host of challenges. It's a good idea to make sure you know what you're doing when working with threads.

See also:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread

[Tkinter understanding mainloop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29158220/tkinter-understanding-mainloop)

[When do I need to call mainloop in a Tkinter application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683217/when-do-i-need-to-call-mainloop-in-a-tkinter-application)

Comment: `tkinter` doesn't always play nice with `threading` so it's recommended that you only call `tkinter` methods from the thread where you created the `tk.Tk`. This solution can cause bigger problems in the future if OP isn't really careful.

Answer (score -1):

```
import time
def update_label():

   ///update label text here

    label.config(text="New label text")
/// wait for 5 seconds before updating the label

time.sleep(5)
update_label()
```

Comment: `///` is not a comment in Python.